# 2 Controllers and 1 Value in AngluarJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to have a global variable and I'm also practicing with factory and service feature of AngularJS and suddendly I counter this weird error. This is the error: (In my index.html file, I use ngRepeat like regular, seems like this error is only brought up when 2 controllers share a global variable)

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=item%20in%20sharedvalue&p1=number%3A0&p2=0
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:6:417
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:234:39
    at Object.fn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:122:291)
    at n.$get.n.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:123:356)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:293)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:216:126)
    at HTMLButtonElement.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:32:389)
```

This is my code:

```
 (function(){
      var app = angular.module("app",[]);
      app.factory('MyFactory', function(){
        return{
          a: 'This is a',
          b: 'This is b',
          c: function(){
            this.a+='a';
            this.b+='b';
          }
        }
      });
      app.service('MyService', function(){
        this.a='This is A';
        this.b='This is B';
        this.c = function(){
          this.a+='A';
          this.b+='B';
        }
      });
      app.controller('SharedFactory', function($scope,MyFactory,SharedValue){
        $scope.a = MyFactory.a;
        $scope.b = MyFactory.b;
        $scope.c = MyFactory.c;
        $scope.sharedvalue = SharedValue;
        var i=0;
        $scope.increase = function(){
          SharedValue.push(i);
          i++;
        };
      });
      app.controller('SharedService', function($scope,MyService,SharedValue){
        $scope.a = MyService.a;
        $scope.b = MyService.b;
        $scope.c = MyService.c;
        $scope.sharedvalue = SharedValue;
        var i=0;
        $scope.increase = function(){
          SharedValue.push(i);
          i++;
        };
      });
      app.value('SharedValue', []);

}());
```

Comment: You have duplicates in the array you are `ng-repeat`ing on. Show us some HTML code, or maybe the first sentence I wrote is enough...

Comment: we need to see the DOM, the ng-repeat directive is used in

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear:

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: item in sharedvalue, Duplicate key: number:0, Duplicate value: 0

You have the same key used twice in your `ng-repeat`.  Use `track by`, like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in sharedvalue track by $index"></div>
```